# How do I avoid killing learnable parameters when transforming a tensor into intervals?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have a set of coordinates that are transformed using a neural network model in Pytorch. Each coordinate has an intensity, which is given by a different tensor. I now want to downsample these coordinates, so that only the intensity within a certain range of the coordinates remains.  However, when I'm defining
`within_interval = torch.logical_and( transformed_coordinates > 2, transformed_coordinates <= 3] )`
the trainable parameters from transformed_coordinates get killed. Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a better way of doing this? The within_interval tensor depends on how transformed_coordinates is trained, so it should be possible to keep the learnable parameters, somehow.

Code is given below for clarity. What I mean when I say the learnable parameters are killed is that Model() doesn't inherit the gradients from FunctionModel().

```
def with_radius(tensor):
    r = torch.norm(tensor, p=2, dim=2).unsqueeze(-1)
    new_tensor = r
    return new_tensor


class Scaling(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scaling, self).__init__()
    
    def forward(self, coords):
        r_max = max(with_radius(coords)[0]).item()
        st_r_max = max(with_radius(coord_values)[0]).item()
        return (st_r_max/r_max)*coords


class FunctionModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FunctionModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 4)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(4, 10)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(10, 50)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(50, 20)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(20, output_dim)
        

    def forward(self, r):
        x = r
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.fc5(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_classes=10):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        # Fully Connected
        self.fully_net = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(1, 64),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.Linear(64, n_classes),
        )
        
        self.F = FunctionModel()
        self.scaling = Scaling()
        
    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor, coordinates):
        coordinates = self.scaling(coordinates)
        transformed_coordinates = self.F(with_radius(coordinates))
        transformed_coordinates = abs(self.scaling(transformed_coordinates))

        intensity = input
        
        within_interval = torch.logical_and( transformed_coordinates > 1, transformed_coordinates <= 19)

        figure_value = torch.empty(0)

        # Loop through figures
        for figure_idx in range(len(intensity)):
            z_sum = (intensity[figure_idx][within_interval.squeeze(0)].sum()).unsqueeze(-1)
            figure_value = torch.cat((figure_value, z_sum))

        
        x = self.fully_net(figure_value.unsqueeze(-1))
                
        return x

        
    def trainable_parameters(self):
        # Calculate the number of trainable paramters in the model
        return sum(param.numel() for param in self.parameters() if param.requires_grad)

model = Model()
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about the problem, include more code, and clarify "parameters killed", people will not understand without proper details.

Comment: I have updated my post now to include more details.

Comment: In `FunctionModel.__init__` you trying to recode some value (coordinate) to one-hot encoded learnable ranges, am I right? If it is not your invention, provide a link, if it is your invention, I salute you, but it is research, not an engineering, so wrong hub.